# What does the bitwise or | operator do?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, bit-manipulation

I was reading about flag enums and bitwise operators, and came across this code:

```
enum file{
read = 1,
write = 2,
readandwrite = read | write
}
```

I read somewhere about why there is a inclusive or statement and how there can't be an &, but can't find the article. Can someone please refresh my memory and explain the reasoning?

Also, how can I say and/or? Eg. if dropdown1="hello" and/or dropdown2="hello"....

Thanks

Comment: I can't work out your question, how can something be and and or ? surely that'd just be an or?

Comment: @Martin -- I assumed he was referring to the colloquial phrase "and/or"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**First Question:**

A `|` does a bitwise or; a bit will be set in the result if it is set in the first value or the second value.  (You use it on `enums` to create values that are combinations of other values)  If you were to use a bitwise and, it wouldn't make very much sense.

It gets used as follows:

```
[Flags] 
enum FileAccess{
None = 0,                    // 00000000 Nothing is set
Read = 1,                    // 00000001 The read bit (bit 0) is set
Write = 2,                   // 00000010 The write bit (bit 1) is set
Execute = 4,                 // 00000100 The exec bit (bit 2) is set
// ...
ReadWrite = Read | Write     // 00000011 Both read and write (bits 0 and 1) are set
// badValue  = Read & Write  // 00000000 Nothing is set, doesn't make sense
ReadExecute = Read | Execute // 00000101 Both read and exec (bits 0 and 2) are set
}
// Note that the non-combined values are powers of two, \
// meaning each sets only a single bit

// ...

// Test to see if access includes Read privileges:
if((access & FileAccess.Read) == FileAccess.Read)
```

Essentially, you can test if certain bits in an `enum` are set; in this case we are testing to see if the bits corresponding to a `Read` are set.  Values `Read` and `ReadWrite` would both pass this test (the both have bit zero set); `Write` would not (it does not have bit zero set).

```
// if access is FileAccess.Read
        access & FileAccess.Read == FileAccess.Read
//    00000001 &        00000001 => 00000001

// if access is FileAccess.ReadWrite
        access & FileAccess.Read == FileAccess.Read
//    00000011 &        00000001 => 00000001

// uf access is FileAccess.Write
        access & FileAccess.Read != FileAccess.Read
//    00000010 &        00000001 => 00000000
```

**Second Question:**

I think when you say "and/or", you mean "one, the other or both".  This is exactly what the `||` (or operator) does.  To say "one or the other, but not both", you'd use `^` ( the exclusive or opertor).

Truth tables (true==1, false==0):

```
     A   B | A || B 
     ------|-------
OR   0   0 |    0
     0   1 |    1 
     1   0 |    1
     1   1 |    1 (result is true if any are true)

     A   B | A ^ B 
     ------|-------
XOR  0   0 |    0
     0   1 |    1 
     1   0 |    1
     1   1 |    0  (if both are true, result is false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The above or is a bitwise or, not a logical or.  1 | 2 is equivalent to 3 (while 1 & 2 = 0).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation for a better explanation about bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumeration Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx). Look at the Enumeration Types as Bit Flags section, it gives an example an OR as well as an example of a AND NOT b.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two different questions here, but to answer #2, the logical OR as found in most programming languages is what you mean by and/or, I think.

```
if (dropdown == "1" || dropdown == "2") // Works if either condition is true.
```

Exclusive-OR however means, "One or the other but not both".