# When using RegisterHotKey api call, why does it accept 1, 2, 4, and 8 as modifiers?

Tags: c#, enums, pinvoke, flags

I reference to this post;

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterHotKey.html

```
    #region fields
    public static int MOD_ALT = 0x1;
    public static int MOD_CONTROL = 0x2;
    public static int MOD_SHIFT = 0x4;
    public static int MOD_WIN = 0x8;
    public static int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;
    #endregion

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    private static int keyId;
    public static void RegisterHotKey(Form f, Keys key)
    {
        int modifiers = 0;

        if ((key & Keys.Alt) == Keys.Alt)
            modifiers = modifiers | WindowsShell.MOD_ALT;

        if ((key & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
            modifiers = modifiers | WindowsShell.MOD_CONTROL;

        if ((key & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
            modifiers = modifiers | WindowsShell.MOD_SHIFT;

        Keys k = key & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift & ~Keys.Alt;

        Func ff = delegate()
            {
                keyId = f.GetHashCode(); // this should be a key unique ID, modify this if you want more than one hotkey
                RegisterHotKey((IntPtr)f.Handle, keyId, modifiers, (int)k);
            };

        f.Invoke(ff); // this should be checked if we really need it (InvokeRequired), but it's faster this way
    }
```

My question is, how does `RegisterHotKey` api know that `1`, `2`, `4`, `8` are windows keys? Because the key codes for ctrl, shift, and menu (alt) give back totally different values for the keys? And what exactly is going on in the `RegisterHotKey` function where it's checking for:

```
if ((key & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
                modifiers = modifiers | WindowsShell.MOD_CONTROL;
```

and what is it doing here?

```
Keys k = key & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift & ~Keys.Alt;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MOD_ALT`, `MOD_CONTROL`, etc don't have any relationship to the keycodes of the associated keys.

You're seeing an `enum` type used to represent a set of [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx).  This is a particularly compact way of representing states that represent combinations of things (like modifier keys being simultaneously pressed, file access permissions, etc)

When `enum`s are used this way, each bit of a variable of the enumeration type can be used to indicate that a particular "flag" is set.

```
// Note that powers of 2 are used; each value has only a single bit set
public static int MOD_ALT = 0x1;     // If bit 0 is set, Alt is pressed
public static int MOD_CONTROL = 0x2; // If bit 1 is set, Ctrl is pressed
public static int MOD_SHIFT = 0x4;   // If bit 2 is set, Shift is pressed 
public static int MOD_WIN = 0x8;     // If bit 3 is set, Win is pressed

// If we wanted to represent a combination of keys:
int altAndControl = MOD_ALT | MOD_CONTROL; // == 3
int controlAndShift = MOD_CONTROL | MOD_SHIFT; // == 6
```

This has two advantages:

- The API doesn't have to take an individual boolean parameter for every modifier key
- The API can be expanded to include additional modifier keys without changing the interface

Bitwise `&`s and `|`s can be used to determine which flags are set in a value, and to set or unset a flag in a value.

The code you've asked about does exactly this:

```
if ((key & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) 
   modifiers = modifiers | WindowsShell.MOD_CONTROL
```

is saying "If the key has the `Control` bit set, then set the control bit in `modifiers`"

```
Keys k = key & ~Keys.Control & ~Keys.Shift & ~Keys.Alt;
```

is saying "`k` is assigned `key` with the `Control`, `Shift` and `Alt` flags cleared"

I'm not sure why the contributors to pinvoke chose to use constants; you can just as easily use a proper enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Modifiers
{
   None = 0,
   Alt = 1,
   Control = 2,
   // ...
}
```

[My answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612072/question-on-operators/612116#612116) has some more details on how flags work, and more examples.

Comment: Would this work in the same fashion?
[Flags()]
public enum KeyModifiers
{
 None = 0,
 Alt = 1, 
 Control = 2,
 Shift = 4,
 Windows = 8
}

The part that confuses me the most is the modifiers argument. How does fsModifiers know that 0x2 == the CTRL key? Is that an internal func. from the dll api?

Comment: Yes, that is internal to the API.

Comment: And does it only contain keys for 1, 2, 4, 8? What are the other keys in between like 3, 5, 6, and 7? What if I wanted to use the L Shift or Right Shift specifically? MSDN says: VK_LSHIFT (0xA0) == Left SHIFT key and VK_RSHIFT (0xA1) == Right SHIFT key;Is there any info for all possible flags?

Comment: @Mike: Remember, each key is mapped to a single bit.  (1, 2, 4, 8 all have a single bit set)  3 has two bits set, and would represent ALT and CTRL being pressed together (3 == ALT | CTRL)

Answer (score 1):

1, 2, 4, 8 are used to represent single bits. 1 is the least significant bit will be on. Adding 2 will turn on the 2nd least significant bit, etc. Thus you can set multiple flags independently of each other.

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
4 = 0100
8 = 1000
```

Thus if you want to set the variables represented by 2 and 4 to be true you would use 0110  = 6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know more about the RegisterHotKey API, take a look here:

[API Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309.aspx)

Also, download the Platform SDK to look at WinUser.h for the definition values for MOD_ALT, MOD_CONTROL, etc.