# What type of parameter argument allows a pipe '|' in the arguments list?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the bitwise or | operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612072/what-does-the-bitwise-or-operator-do)

```
new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
```

What does the method signature that accepts this constructor call look like?

I never knew I could use the '|' operator in a method call. I would like to know more about it.

What is the English word for the '|' operator? (I don't even know how to google it as I do not know a word to describe it)

When it is used in a method, how do I explain it to another developer?

Would you recommend that I include this operator in my bag of tricks?

Does the operator have any special caveats?

Comment: That is the bitwise OR operator, and I don't blame your for posting a duplicate. Operators are usually a PITA to search for.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx

Comment: In this case, the bitwise-OR operator is combining two values of an enumeration decorated with the [Flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx). There's nothing special about the *parameter*, it'll just be of type `FontStyle`.

Comment: You can put any operator at all in a argument, as arguments take any expression with the type of the parameter and you can always figure out some expression that'll have the type in question.

Answer (score 9):

The signature of the accepting method just looks like:

```
public Font(Font prototype, FontStyle newStyle)
{
    ...
}
```

The `|` operator (bitwise-or) in this context means that the font should be both bold *and* italic. It works like this because `FontStyle` is an `enum` decorated with a `FlagsAttribute`. The `FontStyle` definition is:

```
[Flags]
public enum FontStyle
{
    Bold = 1,
    Italic = 2,
    Regular = 0,
    Strikeout = 8,
    Underline = 4
}
```

So when you say `FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic`, it is bitwise-OR:

```
FontStyle.Bold                    = 1 = 00000001
FontStyle.Italic                  = 2 = 00000010
                                        ========
FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic = 3 = 00000011
```

Later, you can test the `style` parameter to see which bits are set using another bitwise operators (`&`). For example, if you want to see if the resulting style above is Bold, you can do:

```
FontStyle myStyle = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
bool isBold = (myStyle & FontStyle.Bold) == FontStyle.Bold;
```

For example, the `Bold` property on the `Font` class checks if `FontStyle.Bold` was part of the style you gave it using almost the same code as above:

```
public bool Bold
{
    get
    {
        return ((this.Style & FontStyle.Bold) != FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}
```

Note that starting in .NET Framework 4 you could use [`Enum.HasFlag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netframework-4.0) to test the presence of a flag. For example, the above property definition could be reduced to (using a little syntactic sugar from C# 6):

```
public bool Bold => this.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Bold);
```